# Including an image in a servicestack model

Tags: servicestack

I'm looking for a good strategy to include an image into a service stack model (if it is possible).  I've searched for examples or tips, but haven't had much luck.

Something like

```
class House
{
    string Address;
    //Image could be anything as long as it can be returned and viewed as a picture in a  
      browser.     
    Image Picture;
}
```

Can this be returned as a part of a Response and properly displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rarely a good idea to include binary blob data directly in a DTO payload.

#### Send Binary Data with Binary Formats

The only formats where it makes sense to do is when using binary formats like [ServiceStack's](http://www.servicestack.net) support for [ProtoBuf](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Protobuf-format) or [Message Pack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MessagePack-Format) formats which wont penalize you for encoding binary data. In which case you would serialize the image into a `byte[]` property on the DTO. If you try to do this in a text format you would need to encode the binary data with a Base64-like format, un-necessary bloating the payload and adding computational overhead.

#### Embed urls to images or binary files instead

The recommended approach is instead of embedding the Image directly in the DTO, to only include a Url that references the image. ServiceStack has great support for returning raw binary or text data where you can simply return any `byte[]`, `Image`, `Stream`, `IStreamWriter`, raw `strings`, etc and it will serialize them as expected.

#### ServiceStack's support for raw binary or text responses

A good example of this can be seen in the new Image Resizer [imgur.servicestack.net](http://imgur.servicestack.net) or the [RestFiles](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RestFiles/RestFiles.ServiceInterface/FilesService.cs) example demos.

Here's some more info about custom HTTP Responses on the wiki:

- [Return any response](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Service-return-types)
- [Customizing HTTP Responses](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Customize-HTTP-Responses)
- [Consuming raw data with typed service clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#support-for-native-built-in-response-types)
- [Consuming raw data from 3rd Party APIs with built-in HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils)